# GDB cannot step into function, OZone can

Tags: arm, gdb, embedded

I have a setup like this:

- GDB from "GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain" 10.3-2021.10
- GDB server from "Segger JLink" 7.54d
- JLink Ultra+ connected to my PC and my embedded device
- Arm Compiler 6.15

I'm having problems stepping into a certain function from a C module (let's call it "F1"). When trying, I get the error message

```
Single stepping until exit from function "F1", which has no line number information.
```

If I use Segger Ozone, with the same .elf file, stepping into "F1" works fine.

I've tried to narrow down the problem and have the following observations:

1. A single line of code from the C module holding "F1" makes the difference. If I remove this line, it works. This line is a simple incrementation (++) of a static uint32_t variable and it is in a separate function (i.e. not "F1").
2. If I don't link with "--inline" option, it stops working - even with the "fix" in (1)

All source files (a mix of C and C++ files) are compiled with -g option.

I may try to reproduce it in a much smaller context which I could share here but until then, I'm hoping for some hints.

Anything is appreciated.

[Update 2021-11-10] Tried with older/newer versions of "GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain" as well as "Segger JLink". Same problem.

[Update 2021-11-10] Compiler/linker command used:

```
armclang -g --target=arm-arm-none-eabi -mcpu=cortex-m33 -mfloat-abi=soft -MMD -Werror -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I<my_include_paths>

armlink --inline --info=sizes --info=veneers --info=unused --info=totals --map --symbols --scatter=<my_scatter_file> --list=list.txt
```

Comment: Include the build command that executed the compiler and linker (that is we need to know _all_ the compiler and linker switched used).  It seems likely that you have compiled with optimisation enabled.  For source-level debugging to make any kind of sense, do not apply optimisation to maintain a one-to-one relationship between the generated code and the source.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for your input. I've updated the post with the information.